# Magento 2.4.0: Retuning - 'This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.'

Tags: magento2.4

After a fresh install of Magento 2.4.0 i am unable to access the main site or Admin page due to: 'This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.'

**Setup:**

/etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin magento_admin@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2
     ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX
     ServerAlias www.Domain.co.uk
     <Directory "/var/www/html/magento2/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/magento-error_log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/magento-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

My Apache.config contains:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Unsecureurl: `--base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/`

Actions so far:

- Performed all the steps suggested under: https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-404-error-page-not-found-admin-url-magento-2/
- reapplied file permissions using:

  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento
  sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento
- replaced the .htaccess file in root with the one under pub/
- Confirmed domain is pointing to correct directory on Magento server

Server specs: Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4.

Please let me know if you have any further recommendations/things I can check.

Thank you

---

1. Use proper formatting for your code samples (the apache virtual host configuration is unreadable) - Done
2. 

```
  magento_admin@localhost:/$ apachectl configtest
            Syntax OK
    
    magento_admin@localhost:/$ apachectl -S
    VirtualHost configuration:
    *:80                   XX.XX.X.XX (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/magento2.conf:1)
    ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
    Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
    Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
    Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
    Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
    Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
    Mutex proxy: using_defaults
    PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
    Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
    Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
    User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
    Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

3. 

```
magento_admin@localhost:/$ a2ensite magento2
Site magento2 already enabled
```

4. No obvious startup errors:

   ```
   [Mon Aug 31 16:15:00.367270 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8558$]
    [Mon Aug 31 16:15:00.372145 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8558$]
    [Mon Aug 31 16:15:00.372178 2020] [core:notice] [pid 85589:tid$]
   ```

Comment: Please edit your question and
- use proper formatting for your `code samples` (the apache virtual host configuration is unreadable)
- add the output of these commands: `apachectl configtest` and `apachectl -S` (do not forget to remove any confidential values like domains and ip addresses)
- check if your virtual host is enabled (symlinked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`)
- if it is not enabled: enable your virtual host configuration with this command: `a2ensite magento2` and restart your webserver: `apachectl restart`
- check this file for startup errors: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Thanks for your response Torsten. I've edited my question with answers to the above. Much appreciated.